# How to have block scopes in ECMAScript 5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

When I was reading about ES 6 features, I found `let`which is used to create block scopes. This [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/use-ecmascript-6-today--net-31582) has nice explanation on ES6 features and let statement. So how do developers create this `block scopes` in older versions of ECMAScript, like ES5.

The following code snippet explains `let`

```
var es = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let c = i;
  es[i] = function () {
    console.log("Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES" + c);
  };
}
es[6](); // Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES6
```

What is the equivalent code in ES5?

Above code snippet without `let`, outputs `10` for `i` since it is in global scope.

```
var es = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  es[i] = function () {
    console.log("Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES" + i);
  };
}
es[6](); // Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES10
```

This [link](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5) has ES6 equivalents in ES5 and it recommends to use `IIFE` for block scopes. But I am not sure, how to use IIFE in the current scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically you just need to make an anonymous function, and use `var` there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it recommends to use IIFE for block scopes.

In ES5, only calling a function creates a new scope. So "obviously", if you want to create a new scope (per iteration), you have to call a function. That's what an IIFE does: It creates a new function and calls it immediately.

Any variable that would be block scoped (e.g. via `let`) would become a parameter of the function and initial values would be passed as arguments.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(c) {
    es[i] = function () {
      console.log("Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES" + c);
    };
  }(i));
}
```

This is simplified of course and there may be cases that would require more elaborate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The current best practice is to write ES2015 (ES6) and run your code through a preprocessor like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Babel takes of the implementation details of supporting `let` on older browsers.

If you want to use ES5 directly, you can [create an anonymous function](https://jsfiddle.net/q6zkm0zd/) that is passed the value of `i` in each iteration.

```
var es = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    es[i] = function () {
      console.log("Upcoming edition of ECMAScript is ES" + i);
    };
  })(i);
}
es[6]();
```

Comment: Your solution does not use closures at all (of course, every function in JS is a closure, but you are not making us of that). You are using the function for a different reason.

Comment: I agree, I was mistaken about the terminology.